# Python: TypeError: string indices must be integers in python

Tags: python, string, azure, azure-blob-storage

Hi I am trying to Upload a file into the blob storage using python, but while doing so i am getting the following error

**TypeError: string indices must be integers**

Currently My code looks like this

```
import os
import yaml
from azure.storage.blob import ContainerClient

def load_config():
    dir_root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    with open(dir_root + "/config.yaml","r") as yamlfile:
        return yaml.load(yamlfile, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)

def get_files(dir):
    with os.scandir(dir) as entries:
            for entry in entries:
                if entry.is_file() and not entry.name.startswith('.'):
                    yield entry

config =load_config()
csvs =get_files(config["source_folder"]+"/csvs")
print(*csvs)
```

Comment: which line is the error ? is it for config["source_folder"]? are you sure config is a dict{} ?

Comment: Yes Yes. Its correct. I made the program by referencing this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=enhJfb_6KYU

Comment: Please provide the entire stacktrace, formatted in the question

Comment: print the type of config and double check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I have tried to reproduce in my environment I uploaded a file into the blob storage using python successfully***

Please use this below code to upload a file into the blob storage

```py
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient
    import json
    twilioMetadata ={1:'dhoni',2:'rohit',3:'virat',4:'raina',5:'yuvaraj'}
    Body = json.dumps(twilioMetadata)
    print(Body)
    blob_service_client  = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string("<connection string>")
    blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client("container1",blob="upload2.json")
    blob_client.upload_blob(Body)
```

For connection string, ***in storage account -> shared access signature -> "Enable the container" in allowed resource types -> click Generate sas and connection string -> copy connection string***

**Output**:

[image]

***Finally,*** my files are uploaded in an azure blob storage successfully as below.

[image]

**Note:** Based on python code drafted above response and output I have not used your code.